# Cocoapods Intall ERROR: While executing gem (TypeError)

Tags: ruby, cocoapods

I have a problem when I try to install the cocoapods gem on Mac.  When I typed in:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

on terminal, it shows the error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (TypeError)
        no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

How do I install the cocapods gem on Mac?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Зелёный  is there still any issue in my question?

Comment: I fixed my problem by Segiddins`s answer. ^ ^

Comment: This is on-topic, as I'll explain: The OP posted a minimal, complete and verifiable example.  This is a programming tool problem, not a code problem (but on-topic, as we do deal with programming tool problems here).  There's nothing the OP could really do to try to solve the problem.  And, the OP has posted an answer.  This question with its answer has value for other programmers who encounter this problem.

Comment: @GerardRoche check the version of  your rubygems, According to Segiddins`s  suggestion,  it is a bug which has been fixed on version 2.6.2. So try to  upgrade rubygems 2.6.2. When I did, the error has gone, good luck~

Comment: @WayneConrad really helpful, thank you for your work, I will pay more attention on my description.

Comment: You're welcome.  You're doing fine.  By the way, you can award your own answer the checkmark once some time has gone by.  That way, others finding this question will be able to see quickly that your answer solved the problem for you.

Answer (score 3):

Luckly, I solved this by check this [Upgrading to rubygems 2.5.x breaks future up/downgrades](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1560)

Accordding to what Segiddins said, this problem might be a bug in the old version, which has been fixed in RubyGems 2.6.2, just try **upgrading your gems to RubyGems 2.6.2**.

Comment: @Rajesh Try the latest version of  RubyGems, bro，if you have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error. Try below command

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

and see if it works.